# How can "IConfiguration object is registered with DI by default" in Startup.cs in .NET Core 2

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, configuration, asp.net-core-2.0

In, aspnet core 2, when we want to to Access configuration during startup, we can do it thanks to dependency injection as far as I understood.

For this code in below, how can we pass `IConfiguration` object to this class with benefits of Dependency Injection ;

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

I saw a sentence:

***" The IConfiguration object is registered with DI by default."***

How can we succeed this?

In *program.cs* there is a code like this, do we set `IConfiguration` object in *startup.cs* class with this code below? I thought .UseStartup()
code carries out this job(passing IConfiguration object to Startup class)  for us. But how?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(SetupConfiguration)
          .UseStartup<Startup>();

    private static void SetupConfiguration(WebHostBuilderContext ctx, IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        //Remove the default configuration options
        builder.Sources.Clear();

        builder.AddJsonFile("config.json", false, true).
            AddEnvironmentVariables();
    }
}
```

I would be so happy if someone can explain this with deep details.

Comment: Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration)

Comment: Thank yo but I read this document and I could not clear up question I asked. I wanted to know how can we initialize  IConfiguration  obejct in Startup class.

Comment: What do you mean "but how"? If you're that curious, read the source code. Big hint: You call `.Build()` on the webhost builder. What do you think that does?

Answer (score 0):

The dependency injection is handled internally for you for the `IConfiguration` instance. The technical details are easy to find if you browse around the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet). In this case, there is a helper class that mimics a basic DI container, you can see this [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/4e44025a52e4b73aa17e09a8041b0e166e0c5ce0/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/GenericHost/GenericWebHostBuilder.cs#L353).

Comment: Thanks but I could not see  "public static IWebHostBuilder UseStartup<TStartup>(this IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder) where TStartup : class"  method     definition in there.   Anyway, you mentioned about this method initialize my Tstartup class (which names Startup in the example)  ? If you can see definition of this method and post, I would be so happy

Comment: That method eventually delegates to [this method](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/4e44025a52e4b73aa17e09a8041b0e166e0c5ce0/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/GenericHost/GenericWebHostBuilder.cs#L222) which is where the psuedo DI comes into play. The `Startup` class gets created [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/4e44025a52e4b73aa17e09a8041b0e166e0c5ce0/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/GenericHost/GenericWebHostBuilder.cs#L243) which calls in turn uses the `IServiceCollection` object I originally mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, It becomes more clear. You are sure that the method I wrote which has generic declaration, eventually calls the method you linked , if it is true , yes I understand.